# Access ACS Azure from Winforms

Tags: winforms, azure, acs

I have an Azure webrole that requires ACSv2 authentication that I want to access from a winforms application.  Many of my clients use Windows XP so I can not use the WIF (which is not available on Windows XP).  What is the best way to get an authentication token for my web request in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For desktop applications you can do the following:

1. Get the list of identity providers from your ACS namespace
2. Display these in a WebBrowser control
3. After the user logs in, get the token from the WebBrowser control and parse it.

This is **similar** to when you want to use ACS in a Windows Phone application. I suggest you take a look at this blog post: [Azure ACS on Windows Phone 7](http://blog.tylerdoerksen.com/2011/04/12/azure-acs-on-windows-phone-7/). And here is the sample code which parses the token after the user logs in through the WebBrowser control (on WP7):

```
private void SignInWebBrowserControl_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e) 
{ 
    var acsResponse = ACSResponse.FromJSON(e.Value);

    RequestSecurityTokenResponse rstr = null; 
    Exception exception = null; 
    try 
    { 
        string binaryToken = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(acsResponse.securityToken); 
        string tokenText = RequestSecurityTokenResponseDeserializer.ProcessBinaryToken(binaryToken); 
        DateTime expiration = DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(acsResponse.expires – acsResponse.created);

        rstr = new RequestSecurityTokenResponse 
                    { 
                        Expiration = expiration, 
                        TokenString = tokenText, 
                        TokenType = acsResponse.tokenType 
                    };
```

Comment: I would like to mark this as answered.  The `ValidateRequest` method in the `OnAuthenticateRequest` event handler works correctly, but the request to the authentication manager to `Authenticate` with the created `ClaimsPrincipal` fails. The principal is not authentication and the whole show stops there.  I suppose that it is a configuration problem, but I am unable to determine the source of the failure.

Comment: Okay.  I have gotten this to work.  My problem (and I don't really understand it) was that I was sending the web request `http://localhost/contacts/Directory` as in the sample and the post authenticate call back was being fired, once for that url (which authenticated correctly and once for `http://localhost/contacts/Directory/` which did not.  I added a slash to the Url and the test now works.

Comment: To implement this as a winforms application, we must change the HttpUtility (for url encoding), the location of the token storage and use the web browser's `ObjectForScripting` property to implement the notify.